# Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, xx])

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, pytorch, batch-normalization

Consider the following network snippet:

```
def __init__(self, model, n_class, dropout_rate,device):
    super(NewModel, self).__init__()

    self.bert = model
    self.linear = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, 2)
    self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, self.bert.config.hidden_size)

    self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate
    self.dropout_1 = nn.Dropout(p = self.dropout_rate)

    self.activation = nn.LeakyReLU()

    self.bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features = self.bert.config.hidden_size)

def forward(self, batch):
    outputs = self.bert(
        input_ids = batch[0].to(self.device),
        attention_mask = batch[1].to(self.device),
        token_type_ids = None,
        position_ids = None,
        head_mask = None,
        inputs_embeds = None,
    )

    output = outputs[0]
    pooled_output=output[:,0]
    pooled_output = pooled_output.unsqueeze(0)

    pooled_output_1 = self.dropout_1(self.bn(pooled_output))

    logits = self.linear(F.leaky_relu(self.linear_1(pooled_output_1)))
```

My batch size is 16 and during training I get this error:

```
ValueError: Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, 16])
```

I already set `drop_last=True` in the `DataLoader`, but the error persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions of your tensors are not correct: the batch size should always come first (and the error `was got input size torch.Size([1, 16])`). The pytorch dataloader loads data with the following shape: (batch_size, input_tensor_size). Hence, `input_ids` is fed with the first element of your batch, and `attention_mask` with the second one, which I assume is not what you wanted (except if you reshaped the tensor outputted by the dataloader which would be the origin of the error)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `BatchNorm` and it is expected to have `batch_dim` > 1
So Please do `model.eval()` before passing the input during testing